# valor de variables dentro de ciclo

Tags: java

Realizaba este ejercicio,

> Leer por cada aprendiz de Salud Ocupacional su número de
>   identificación y su calificación en cada una de las 5 unidades de la
>   materia. Al final que escriba el número de identificación del aprendiz
>   que obtuvo mayor promedio. Suponga que los aprendices tienen
>   diferentes promedios.

Al cual resolví de la siguiente manera,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nestudiante, cedula, contadorestudiante=0, posicion=0, posicionmayor=0, j=0, estudiantemayorpromedio;
    float nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, nota5, promediomayor=0, promedio;

    //Pedimos la cantidad de estudiantes a tratar
    nestudiante=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de estudiantes de salud ocupacional"));

    //Creamos el arreglo con dicha cantidad
    int[] identificaciones=new int [nestudiante];

    //Creamos arreglo bidimensional de promedios

    float [] promedios_estudiantes=new float[nestudiante];

    //Creamos un bucle for para rellenar el arreglo con la identificacion de los estudiantes
    for (int i = 0; i < nestudiante; i++) {

        //Pedimos la cedula del estudiante para el arreglo
        cedula=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el número de identificación del estudiante"));

        identificaciones[i]=cedula;

            nota1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digita la nota 1"));
            nota2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digita la nota 2"));
            nota3=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digita la nota 3"));
            nota4=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digita la nota 4"));
            nota5=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digita la nota 5"));

            promedio=(nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4+nota5)/5;

            promedios_estudiantes[j]=promedio; //Promedio del estudiante

            promediomayor=promedios_estudiantes[0];//Inicializamos el Promedio mayor al primer valor del arreglo promedios

            posicionmayor=identificaciones[0]; //PROBLEMAAAA

            // Creamos un condicional para que guarde el promedio mayor y 
            // la posicion cuando los resultados de J superen a los ya
            // establecidos
            if (promedios_estudiantes[j]>promediomayor) {
                promediomayor=promedios_estudiantes[j];
                posicionmayor=identificaciones[i];
            }
            j++;//Aumentamos en 1 el iterador de promedios
        }//Fin del For


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El estudiante con mayor promedio es: \n Número de Identificación: "+posicionmayor+"\n Promedio: "+promediomayor);

    System.exit(0);

    }
```

El problema resulta en la linea que dice `PROBLEMAAAAAAA`, en esta parte el problema resulta en una falta de concordancia, resulta que si ejecutamos el código sin esta linea, el programa no guarda la identificación del estudiante, lo cual me parece raro porque yo tengo inicializada la variable `posicionmayor=0` al principio del `main`.

Lo que me hizo pensar que seguramente sin la linea de arriba (promediomayor) iba a tener el mismo problema con el guardado del promedio, PERO NO, yo borre la linea de arriba de arriba, dejando únicamente su nacionalización en 0 al principio del main y este funcionó perfectamente.

Mi pregunta es ¿Porque no puedo prescindir de esta linea de código?
¿Al borrar esta linea, que le impide a mi programa guardar la identificación? Se supone que los condicionales están perfectos, y el asignarle a la variable un 0 o cualquier otro, es totalmente indiferente a la hora de comparar < o > según otro numero.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta esta bien estructurada, pero el codigo no termina de entenderse.. tal vez porque trataste de comentarlo en el medio del codigo, con lo cual tus lineas problematicas no queda claro donde estan. Podiras tratar de arreglar eso? pensa que no vemos tu programa en una ide, solo aca. Usa el boton [edit]

Comment: Pega todo el método main de una sola vez. Las cosas que comentas no coinciden con el código que has puesto. Hablas de `posicionmayor=identificaciones[0];` y yo no lo veo, lo que veo es `posicionmayor=identificaciones[i];`. Y luego pon comentarios en las líneas que te fallan o sobre las cuales necesitas ayuda. Tal como lo tienes es bastante difícil ayudarte.

Comment: En esta línea:     posicionmayor=identificaciones[i]; ¿no deberia ser jota?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que las líneas

```
promediomayor=promedios_estudiantes[0];
posicionmayor=identificaciones[0];
```

están dentro del ciclo for, y las variables promediomayor y posicionmayor siempre guardan el primer valor de su vector correspondiente. Entonces cuando haces la comparación

```
promedios_estudiantes[j] > promediomayor
```

el valor de promediomayor no es realmente el mayor xd, sino que esa variable está guardando el valor de promedios_estudiantes[0].

En cada iteración del ciclo for estás 'borrando' los valores de esas variables despues de hacer la comparación y les estás reasignando los valores de promedios_estudiantes[0] e identificaciones[0].

Solo bastaría con que borres esas dos líneas de código para que el programa funcione  bien.